# Is it possible to configure clickhouse data storage to be hdfs

Tags: hadoop, hdfs, clickhouse

Currently, clickhouse stores data on

> /var/lib/clickhouse

path and I've read It doesn't have support for deep storage. 
By the way, does it have any configs for hdfs setup in config.xml file?

Comment: If you've not found it in the documentation, then I don't think asking here will help you find the answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

store clickhouse datadir into HDFS it's a really BAD idea ;)

cause HDFS not posix compatible file system, clickhouse will be extremly slow on this deployment variant

you can use https://github.com/jaykelin/clickhouse-hdfs-loader to load data from HDFS into clickhouse, and in near future https://clickhouse.yandex/docs/en/roadmap/ clickhouse may will be support PARQUET format for loading data

clickhouse have own solution for High Availability and Clusterization 
please read 
https://clickhouse.yandex/docs/en/operations/table_engines/replication/ and https://clickhouse.yandex/docs/en/operations/table_engines/distributed/

Comment: if anyone wants to use https://github.com/jaykelin/clickhouse-hdfs-loader but have their in json or avro format, can have a look at https://github.com/akshaymegharaj/clickhouse-hdfs-loader. Added support for json & avro to the above mentioned repository.

Comment: @Slach, can you explain more why it is bad idea?

Comment: @MajidHajibaba
https://stackoverflow.com/a/71873648/1204665

Comment: @Slach is this still true?

Comment: @Switch386
you can try HDFS + local cache https://clickhouse.com/docs/en/operations/storing-data/#configuring-hdfs

still slower than local disk

Comment: @Slach thanks, it seems like this is would introduce latency on the network hop. in process > out of process > completely distributed. if HDFS is high-throughput, the clickhouse server becomes more-or-less stateless, so you could autoscale that on the fly. intuitively, it feels like this is good when solving for high traffic or possibly CPU-intensive work, but your common use case or large aggregations that read much of any table would be worsened. which use cases would this be good for?

Answer (score 2):

@MajidHajibaba

clickhouse designed initially for data locality, it means you have local disk and data will read from local disk as fast as possible

3 years later, S3 and HDFS as remote data storage with local caching is good implemented approach

look https://clickhouse.com/docs/en/engines/table-engines/mergetree-family/mergetree/#table_engine-mergetree-s3 fo details
look to `cache_enabled` and `cache_path` options

and https://clickhouse.com/docs/en/operations/storing-data/#configuring-hdfs

Comment: thanks for describing. However, due to SO rules, it would better if you edit your posts to describe more instead of new post.

Answer (score 1):

HDFS engine provides integration with Apache Hadoop ecosystem by allowing to manage data on HDFSvia ClickHouse. This engine is similar to the File and URL engines, but provides Hadoop-specific features.

https://clickhouse.yandex/docs/ru/operations/table_engines/hdfs/